# How to configure a single site to use proxy settings?

Tags: macos, networking, proxy

A bit tricky, but I need my Chrome to use HTTPS proxy settings for only a single site.

All that I could find was related to exclude some sites:

[image]

I actually need to include just one or two and exclude all of the rest

Answer (score 3):

Proxying a single site can be achieved by a [Proxy Auto Configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config)-script. You can create it manually, but there are also services like [Cloudonymus](https://cloudnymous.com/config/proxy) that automates the process. [Here](https://cloudnymous.com/connect/osx/proxy) is their guide for enabling PAC on OS X.

This was a way to complex answer:

One way to solve this is to use the firewall ([ipfw](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/ipfw.8.html)) to redirect requests to the desired IP to an internal HTTP-proxy (for example Squid). Then [configure Squid](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/CacheHierarchy) to foward all HTTP requests to another proxy. I have only used Squid on Linux, but [SquidMan](http://squidman.net/squidman/) is apparently a nice tool for using and configuiring Squid on OS X.

ipfw lets you match on protocol and port, so it will work also if there are other services running on machines with the same IPs (and you dont want those connections to be proxied). You want to use the fwd-rule of ipfw.